# Heroku - Cloned an app via GitHub, and need to push the to existing app

Tags: git, heroku

**How can I push a cloned app from Github, from my local machine, to an existing Heroku application? What I have done is not working.**

I'm working on an app that I've cloned from GitHub.

I've been told to deploy this app to an existing Heroku account.

The issue is that when I log into Heroku, using the command prompt (heroku login) and then heroku create then git push heroku master, it produces a new app, say App Two.

However, what I wanted to do is push the modified, cloned, app from my local machine to the existing app, called App One. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step 1: You should clone the existing app which you wish to deploy the code using below command.

`heroku git clone -a AppOne`

Step 2: Merge/Update the code which you have in local in AppOne. You can just copy the GitHub modified code to Appone

Step 3: Commit and push the changes done in AppOne.

`git add.`

`git commit -m "Commit message"`

`git push heroku master`

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation jusermar! I've just done it now and it works great.